# Google Places API - how do I increase the free quota to 150,000 requests per day?

Tags: google-places-api

In the Google Developers console, if I choose my API project there is a Quotas tab. Under Billing Status there is a 'Apply for a higher quota' link which links to a page that says..

"The Google Places API Web Service enforces a default limit of 1 000 requests per 24 hour period, which you can increase free of charge. If your app exceeds the limit, the app will start failing. Verify your identity to get up to 150 000 requests per 24 hour period, by enabling billing on the Google Developers Console."

Further down the page there is a button titled Enable Billing (so far so good). When I click that it takes me back to the Google Developers Console and asks me to pick my API project. I then see a message that says Billing Setup Successfully.

I go back to the quotas tab expecting to see the Free Quota increased from 1,000 per day to 150,000 per day but it hasn't changed.

Does anybody know how I can increase the free quota please?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you're seeing in the quotas tab of the API configuration?  It should look something like [this](http://imgur.com/Mq1RgaU).

Answer (score 11):

Sounds like you're talking about this:
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage#verify_your_identity_by_enabling_billing

- Click "Enable Billing"
- Choose the project to enable billing on

Once done, it'll ask you for your credit card information.  Once that's all submitted, what I did was to set a budget of $0 per day to be sure they never billed me anything.

The $0 budget is likely unnecessary since they say they'll won't bill you in their documentation unless you upgrade to premium... but I like that extra level of surety.

After adding enabling billing, hit the top-left menu item and click on "API Manager".  You should see "Google Places API Web Service" listed.  Click on that, and it should tell you your quota of how many requests you've used out of 150,000 possible.