# Bug: Google Places API free quotas number error

Tags: google-api, google-places-api, quota

I have a same problem as below..

[Google Places API - how do I increase the free quota to 150,000 requests per day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33055206/google-places-api-how-do-i-increase-the-free-quota-to-150-000-requests-per-day)

1. I registered my credit card.
2. Max quotas of Google Places API is increased.
3. But free quotas of Google Places API is not changed

Let me know why free quotas is not increased even I certified by credit card. I found some people who have a same problem. but there is no solution..

I found this, but he didn't say how to solve this..
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/kRDZw4uA38I

Please help me..!

Comment: If you have followed Google´s directions but you think the service doesn't work as it should, you need to contact Google to sort it out.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the relation between a service provider and a client.

Comment: Thanks for your kind comments. I wrote here because I couldn't find google support center (contact or email) at google developer page and they recommended to find answer at here. I will close this soon!

Comment: I hope you get your issue sorted out through this: https://developers.google.com/maps/contact-sales/

Comment: Google Cloud support is here https://cloud.google.com/support/

Comment: @Tom Brunberg I wanted this page...! Thanks very much for saving my time. xomena Thanks, too.