# to many request on places api web service, is it possible to do it another way?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api

I'm doing an app using googles api. After only a couple of hours of playing around i noticed i maxed out the place search api.

[image]

I want to be able to search for an address and add it to the map. Am i doing this wrong? Or why have i already created so many request? 
Is it possible to get the addresses elsewhere?

I know it can be hard to say if i'm doing this wrong, but just by the look of the request i thought you might be able to say that my code is doing way to many request.

This is the code i'm using:

```
            $scope.initiateMap = function () {
                $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    zoom: 11
                });
                //var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                //    position: uluru,
                //    map: map
                //});

                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                    var initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                    $scope.map.setCenter(initialLocation);
                }, function () {
                    console.log('user denied request for position');
                    });

                var input = document.getElementById('address-field');
                var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
                //map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

                $scope.map.addListener('bounds_changed', function () {
                    searchBox.setBounds($scope.map.getBounds());
                });

                var markers = [];
                searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function () {
                    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
                    //var address_autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(address_input, { types: ['address'] });
                    //if (places.length == 0) {
                    //    return;
                    //}

                    // Clear out the old markers.
                    markers.forEach(function (marker) {
                        marker.setMap(null);
                    });
                    markers = [];

                    // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
                    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                    places.forEach(function (place) {
                        if (!place.geometry) {
                            console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
                            return;
                        }
                        if (place.types[0] !== "street_address") {
                            alert("not a street address");
                            markers = [];
                            markers.forEach(function (marker) {
                                marker.setMap(null);
                            });
                            return;
                        }
                        $scope.apartment.Address.Longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();
                        $scope.apartment.Address.Latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();

                        $scope.apartment.Address.AddressName = place.formatted_address;
                        var icon = {
                            url: place.icon,
                            size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                            anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
                        };

                        // Create a marker for each place.
                        markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                            map: $scope.map,
                            icon: icon,
                            title: place.name,
                            position: place.geometry.location
                        }));

                        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                            // Only geocodes have viewport.
                            bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
                        } else {
                            bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
                        }
                    });
                    $scope.map.fitBounds(bounds);
                });
            }
```

Comment: in your developer console at google you can see how many requests you made, show code

Comment: the image in the question is from that console. Or do you want another image?

Comment: maybe you can set it up to 150k request like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33055206/google-places-api-how-do-i-increase-the-free-quota-to-150-000-requests-per-day

Comment: and here you have a comparison of alternatives https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-each-Places-API  foursquare is relatively nice

Answer (score 0):

As it is said in Google's guide, you can increase requests limit free of charge, up to 150,000 requests per 24 hour period, by enabling billing on the Google API Console. This is just to verify your identity, so your card won't be charged.

Look [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage?hl=en) for more.

Comment: Great! I'm working on that. It just feels like that 1000 request went by really fast. But maybe thats how it works.